# Getting touchscreen to work in raspbian / kodi

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, kodi, touchscreen

I got a HANNS-G HT231HPB touchscreen which I want to get fully working on raspbian and kodi.

It seems to work in the normal lxde on raspbian, but when I start kodi I get no touch events.

Can someone get me started? Do I need special drivers or libs?

So far, I found this tutorial: http://markamc.traki-iski.co.uk/raspberry-pi-2-osmc-egalax-touchscreen/

Following it everything works fine including the calibration. Just when I go back into Kodi, there is just no cursor.

Comment: This might help: http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=72576&sid=dd85cda95ffa743791efbf5329e7a206